# Why is jthread not presented in libc++ (using clang 18, c++26)

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, c++20, clang++

the following code just compile with "jthread not in std".
with clang 18

```
clang++ -std=c++26 -stdlib=libc++
```

and the implementation of jthread is in __thread/jthread.h, but for some reason macro out.
why?

```
#include <thread>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
  std::jthread t([] { std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s); });
}
```

Comment: per [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20) clang 17 should give that error, not clang 18.  Can you confirm `clang++ --version` is clang 18?

Comment: "_but for some reason macro out_": Well, what macro is it? The name would probably give a hint...

Comment: yes I am sure it is clang 18 (just built from source)

Comment: the lines before jthread says
_LIBCPP_PUSH_MACROS
#include <__undef_macros>

#if _LIBCPP_STD_VER >= 20 && !defined(_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_EXPERIMENTAL_STOP_TOKEN)

and then the rest of the code are out. LIBCPP_STD_VER is 26, so it is LIBCPP_HAS_NO_EXPERIMENTAL_STOP_TOKEN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [libc++ documentation](https://libcxx.llvm.org/) has a webpage about [C++20 status of libc++](https://libcxx.llvm.org/Status/Cxx20.html). Quoting the relevant [footnote 8](https://libcxx.llvm.org/Status/Cxx20.html#note-p0660):

> P0660: The paper is implemented but the features are experimental and can be enabled via `-fexperimental-library`.

Thus, just pass that flag mentioned above when compiling with Clang 18 or newer, like this:

```
clang++ -std=c++26 -stdlib=libc++ -fexperimental-library
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize that jthread is actually not fully supported yet in clang 18's libc++ ...